# How to clean or overwrite RAM and shut down computer by bash script that reacts on keyboard shortcut?

Tags: bash, shell-script, keyboard-shortcuts, ram

My system is protected by Full Disk Encryption.

The weak point of my computer is RAM which lives a bit after computer is off,
containing some important safety information I would like to clean up.
And that's the point, I want to clean or overwrite RAM and shut down my computer by bash script just when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed.

How to do that?

Comment: duplicate on superuser? http://superuser.com/questions/464297/wipe-ram-on-shut-down-to-prevent-cold-boot-attack

Comment: Do you store data worth thousands/millions of dollars that somebody would desperately want to steal? When protecting you consider attacks that are likely. If someone braking into your house and stealing a running computer or hijacking it for long enough to read the data is probable, I'd guess that you should invest in your walls and windows. 10$ crowbar is cheaper and beating you is more effective than decrypting. Unless this does not apply to you.